# Cannot assign values error in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2, xcode7

I am fiddling around with table views and I am stuck with the error **Cannot assign a value of type 'Answer' to a value of type '[Answer]'**

Answer is a class with the following definition:

```
class Answer {
var EnglishAnswer: String = ""
var ChineseAnswer: String = ""
init(newEng: String, newChi: String){
    self.EnglishAnswer = newEng
    self.ChineseAnswer = newChi
}


}
```

And I am running into problems in the prepareforsegue method:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let indexpath: NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
    var DestinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! AnswerTableViewController
    var ArrayofArrayswithAnswerElementsTwo : Answer
    var ArrayofArrayswithAnswerElements = levelsArray.map( { $0.AnswersArray })
    ArrayofArrayswithAnswerElementsTwo = ArrayofArrayswithAnswerElements[indexpath.row]
    DestinationViewController.ArrayofArrayswithAnswerElements = ArrayofArrayswithAnswerElementsTwo

}
```

Comment: Maybe you might want to do `levelsArray.flatMap( { $0.AnswersArray })` to flatten array of arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error clearly stats that you are trying to assign array of `Answer` objects to a variable which is declared to hold only `Answer` objects.

This variable is meant to hold `Answer` object:

```
var ArrayofArrayswithAnswerElementsTwo : Answer
```

And I suspect this line is retuning an array of `Answer` objects:

```
ArrayofArrayswithAnswerElementsTwo = ArrayofArrayswithAnswerElements[indexpath.row]
```

You would need to put a breakpoint, check your model, print objects and check the right assignments in your `prepareForSegue` function.

**Solution:** There could be 2 solutions to your problem:

**First,** define `ArrayofArrayswithAnswerElementsTwo` like this

```
var ArrayofArrayswithAnswerElementsTwo : [Answer]
```

**Second,** make `ArrayofArrayswithAnswerElements[indexpath.row]` to return `Answer` and not `[Answer]`

PS: Naming convention of your variables is off sync with industry practice. Variable names should start with lower case and should be kept as short as possible.

Comment: I don't understand. The error comes up in the bottom two lines and I don't get the difference between [Answer] and Answer

Comment: Yes, I meant your second list line only. What do you get when you print `ArrayofArrayswithAnswerElements[indexpath.row]`? I am sure its an Array. Which you are trying to assign to `ArrayofArrayswithAnswerElementsTwo` which is meant to hold `Answer`. Take a look at my updated post.